# GitHub custom domain, affecting other repositories?

Tags: github, domain, github-pages

I redirected my GitHub main repository to a domain name. It is working fine,

[kongaraju.github.com/kongaraju.github.io](http://kongaraju.github.com/kongaraju.github.io) ===> [kongaraju.in](http://kongaraju.in)

at the same other repository gh-pages are affecting, they are redirecting to custom domain path.

Suppose:

[kongaraju.github.com/resume](http://kongaraju.github.com/resume) ===> [kongaraju.in/resume](http://kongaraju.in/resume)

results not found (404).

How to prevent redirecting other repositories to custom domain?

Answer (score 1):

This is what [dig](http://digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=kongaraju.github.com&type=&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=) tells me:

```
kongaraju.github.com.   3600    IN  CNAME   github.map.fastly.net.
github.map.fastly.net.  17  IN  A   199.27.72.133
```

Because of CNAME entry, any requests to kongaraju.github.com gets resolved to github.map.fastly.net.

Because of the A record, any query to github.map.fastly.net. gets resolved to 199.27.72.133.

It's not possible to (not) redirect only specific repos, because all repos are available on 
`githubusername.hithub.com` & the combination of CNAME & A record entry results in all repos being redirected

Comment: is there any alternative way to show other repos under domain path

Comment: not to my knowledge.